# Defining a command to define an asterisk command

Tags: macros, starred-version

I have the following command `\defmeta` that defines two other commands (one starred and one unstarred)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\newcommand{\genericcmd}[3]{#1 #3 #2 }
\newcommand{\genericcmdstarred}[3]{ #1 starred, #3 #2}
\newcommand{\defmeta}[3]{
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{\genericcmd{#2}{#3}{##1}}
\WithSuffix\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname *[1]{\genericcmdstarred{#2}{#3}{##1}}
}

\defmeta{mynewcommand}{Hello}{world}

\begin{document}
\mynewcommand{big}.
\mynewcommand*{big}.
\end{document}
```

This works perfectly. However, I wonder if there is a way to remove the dependency on `suffix`?
I would like to not use the `suffix` package because I do not want to have unnecessary dependencies and as a way to learn more LaTeX magic.

Comment: [Asterix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix) vs. [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk).

Comment: I would recommend using `xparse` and `\NewDocumentCommand` which supports this out of the box. It is part of the development of the LaTeX 3 project.

Comment: @HenriMenke But you must admit that Asterixed versions of commands would bring a bit of badly needed excitement to many documents!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No dependencies on packages, only on the LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\genericcmd}[3]{#1 #3 #2}
\newcommand{\genericcmdstarred}[3]{#1 starred, #3 #2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\metadef[3]{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname s\string#1\endcsname}{\csname n\string#1\endcsname}%
  }%
  \@namedef{s\string#1}##1{\genericcmdstarred{#2}{#3}{##1}}%
  \@namedef{n\string#1}##1{\genericcmd{#2}{#3}{##1}}%
}
\makeatother

\metadef{\mynewcommand}{Hello}{world}

\begin{document}

\mynewcommand{big}.

\mynewcommand*{big}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

More interesting, perhaps, is a definition without the need to define `\genericcmd` and `\genericcmdstarred`. The command `\metadef` has the same syntax as `\newcommand` (but no `*` version, which could be added with some more trickery), but with an argument more:

```
\metadef{<macro name>}[<args>]{<code for normal version>}{<code for starred version>}
```

Optional arguments to the defined macro are not allowed, use the following `xparse` based code for adding whatever list of arguments you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\metadef}[1]{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname s\string#1\endcsname}{\csname n\string#1\endcsname}%
  }%
  \edef\meta@def@name{\string#1}%
  \meta@def
}
\newcommand\meta@def[3][0]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname n\meta@def@name\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname s\meta@def@name\endcsname[#1]{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\metadef{\mynewcommand}[1]{Hello #1 world}{Hello starred, #1 world}

\begin{document}

\mynewcommand{big}.

\mynewcommand*{big}.

\end{document}
```

---

The same with `suffix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\metadef}[1]{%
  \def\meta@def@name{#1}%
  \meta@def
}
\newcommand\meta@def[3][0]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\meta@def@name[#1]{#2}%
  \WithSuffix\expandafter\newcommand\meta@def@name*[#1]{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\metadef{\mynewcommand}[1]{Hello #1 world}{Hello starred, #1 world}

\begin{document}

\mynewcommand{big}.

\mynewcommand*{big}.

\end{document}
```

---

The same with `xparse`, where you just have to remember of shifting by one the number of the arguments, because `#1` is the possible `*`. The arguments to the “metadefined” macro must be expressed in `xparse` syntax, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\metadef}{mmmm}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s#2}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{#4}{#3}%
  }%
}

\metadef{\mynewcommand}{m}{Hello #2 world}{Hello starred, #2 world}

\begin{document}

\mynewcommand{big}.

\mynewcommand*{big}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great. I was trying to do something like this in the beginning but I didn't know about the `\string` and `@namdef` commands.

Comment: @Tohiko I added what I believe is a more interesting approach.

Comment: The 'more interesting' version is a neat trick.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using `xparse` which is part of the work by the LaTeX 3 project developers.

The following emulates the code in the question except that it eliminates the spurious space caused by the unstarred version of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \mynewcommand { s m }
{%
  Hello
  \IfBooleanT {#1}
  {%
    starred,
  }%
  #2 world%
}

\begin{document}
\mynewcommand{big}.
\mynewcommand*{big}.
\end{document}
```

[image: starry worlds]

Comment: Your version does not define a command that defines a starred command ;-)

Comment: True. Was that the question? Maybe I just didn't get it.

Comment: Yes, that was the question, see the title ;-) Irony is that I answered it that way but it's disregarded. Seems to be my fate here, on TeX.SX ;-)

Comment: I guess I took the goal to be the starred command creation, with the question thinking that creating a new command to do that was necessary as opposed to the goal being the new command itself.

Answer (score 3):

No dependencies on packages, no dependencies on LaTeX kernel:).

```
\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\toks0={#2}\toks1={#3}%
   \let\tmp=#1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA}
\def\isnextcharA{\the\toks\ifx\tmp\next0\else1\fi\space}

\def\metadef#1#2#3{\def#1{\isnextchar*{\metadefA{#3}}{\metadefB{#2}}}}
\def\metadefA#1*{\def\tmp##1{#1}\tmp}
\def\metadefB#1{\def\tmp##1{#1}\tmp}

\metadef \mynewcommand {Hello ##1 world} {Hello starred, ##1 world}

\mynewcommand{big}.

\mynewcommand*{big}.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without any package, using `\@ifstar` and relying on a moving argument, i.e. the #1 command sequence has no real argument, but `\@ifstar` looks for the `*` character and branches into the relevant command either doing this or the other version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\genericcmdunstarred}[3]{#1 #3 #2 }
\newcommand{\genericcmdstarred}[3]{ #1 starred, #3 #2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defmeta}[3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \@ifstar{%
      \genericcmdstarred{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \genericcmdunstarred{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%      
}

\defmeta{mynewcommand}{Hello}{world}

\defmeta{foo}{And now for something}{different}

\begin{document}
\mynewcommand{big}.

\mynewcommand*{big}.

\foo{completely}

\foo*{completely}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this solution relies on the fact that the "variable" argument ("big" or "completely") that is passed to `genericcmd` is the last one, right?

Comment: @Tohiko: Yes, that's a possible caveat.